# Allowed memory size of 138412032 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to develop a PHP composer app with the [Slim PHP Framework](https://github.com/maurobonfietti/rest-api-slim-php), and attempted to make the changes to the `migrations.php` file like this

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__ . '/../../src/App/App.php';

try {
    $settings = $app->getContainer()->get('settings');

    $hostname = $settings['db']['hostname'];
    $username = $settings['db']['username'];
    $password = $settings['db']['password'];
    $database = $settings['db']['database'];

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname", $username, $password); //Possibly the connection
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $database";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "[OK] Database droped successfully" . PHP_EOL;

    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE $database";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "[OK] Database created successfully" . PHP_EOL;

    $sql = "USE $database";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "[OK] Database selected successfully" . PHP_EOL;

    $sql = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../database/database.sql');
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "[OK] Tables created successfully" . PHP_EOL;
//    echo "[OK] Records inserted successfully" . PHP_EOL;
    $data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../database/companies.json');
    $array = json_decode($data, true);
    foreach($array as $row) {
        $relationships = $row["relationships"];

        $pdo->exec($sql);

    }
    echo "[OK] Json inserted into tables successfully" . PHP_EOL;



} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "[ERROR] " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I tried loading in a `companies.json` file, which is 78.5MB in size and when I ran `composer migration`, I ran into the error `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /.../extras/bin/migration.php on line 35`.

I'm still using the same `composer.json` in the repo

```
  {
    "name": "maurobonfietti/rest-api-slim-php",
    "description": "Example of REST API with Slim PHP Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "php",
        "slim-micro-framework",
        "rest-api",
        "mysql",
        "slim3",
        "slim",
        "rest",
        "api"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/maurobonfietti/rest-api-slim-php",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Mauro Bonfietti",
            "email": "mauro.bonfietti@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/maurobonfietti"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
        "palanik/corsslim": "dev-slim3",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "respect/validation": "^1.1",
        "slim/slim": "^3.12.2",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "coverage": "phpunit --coverage-html=coverage --coverage-text",
        "database": "extras/bin/restart-api.sh",
        "restart": "extras/bin/restart-api.sh",
        "migration": "php extras/bin/migration.php",
        "start": "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php",
        "test": "phpunit"
    }
}
```

and I have added a `php.ini` file to my repository at `/docker/php7/php.ini` from [here](https://webhost.ai/download-default-php-ini-files/#download-default-php-ini).

Does anyone mind telling me how to increase the memory limit for my application? I'm quite new to PHP. Let me know if more clarification is needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you can set it via:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '80M');
```

However, this is a bad solution, try not to load whole json file into memory and use something like [jsonstreamingparser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser) .

Answer (score -1):

It is 128M, set `memory_limit = 256M` for instance, hope it helps

(in .ini)

Comment: I have tried this solution, but running `composer migration` still fails and produces the same error message

Comment: And if you increase even more?